# Processing.js: Won't track mouseMoved()?

Tags: mouse, processing

I'm having an issue with tracking the movement of a mouse in a Processing sketch when its ported to Javascript. As far as I can tell, the program runs fine except that it wont activate mouseMoved, either as an event or as a logical operation. I also tried pMousex != mouseX and that also didn't work. Any help?

```
color[] palette = new color[5];
color c1;
color c2;
color c3;
color c4;
color c5;
color bgColor;

int swarmSize;
int xVariance;
int yVariance;
int maxSize;
int maxOpacity;
int maxStroke;

//Non-definables for swarm gen
int sideMod;
int sSize;
int opacity;
int stroke;

void setup() {
size(600, 400);

c1= #BF2633;
c2= #A6242F;
c3= #D9CEAD;
c4= #C0B18F;
c5= #011C26; 

bgColor = color(23, 76, 79);

palette[0] = c1;
palette[1] = c2;
palette[2] = c3;
palette[3] = c4;
palette[4] = c5;

swarmSize = 1;
xVariance = 60;
yVariance = 60;
maxSize = 30;
maxOpacity = 255;
maxStroke = 4;
```

}

```
void draw() { //tried tracking pMouse != mouse here, no dice
}

void drawSwarm() {
  for (int i = 0; i < swarmSize; i++)
{
 if (random(1, 10) < 5) {
  sideMod = -1;
} 
else {
  sideMod = 1;
}
stroke = int(random(1, maxStroke));
sSize = int(random(1, maxSize));
opacity = int(random(0, maxOpacity));

strokeWeight(stroke);
stroke(palette[int(random(1, 5))], opacity);
fill(palette[int(random(1, 5))], opacity);

// strokeWeight(int(random(1, 7)));
ellipse(mouseX + int(random(1, xVariance)) * sideMod, mouseY+ int(random(1, yVariance)), sSize, sSize);
```

}
    }

```
void mouseMoved() { //Doesn't work in processing.js
drawSwarm();
}

void keyPressed() {
background(bgColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine (see http://jsfiddle.net/qPpRQ/)

```
int x,y;
void draw() {
  point(x,y);
}
void mouseMoved() {
  x = mouseX;
  y = mouseY;
  redraw();
}
```

usually, draw instructions in a mouse handler don't work all that well, you generally want to set up your state based on the mouse position, and then call redraw(), with the code that actually draws things to the screen being called from draw, not from your event handler.